# Useful skew is a concept for what phase of physical back-end design?

Tags: clock, skew

The calculation of useful skew takes into account the shortest and longest logic paths. Does this mean that if I need to use useful skew during the CTS phase, then I need to routing the logic cells? Is the same with skew scheduling?

Comment: Which bus or technology are you refering to? Please use specifics

Comment: Sounds to me like it's an FPGA of some sort (reference to logic cells).

Comment: I mean IC physical design, and what I want to talk about is a series of work that netlist has done since the synthesis, CTS stands for clock tree synthesis.

Comment: It's ASIC back-end phase.